# PHP function to determine if date is the last weekday (Mon-Fri) of a month

Tags: php, date

I am trying to figure out a function that will return true if a DateTime date is the last weekday(Mon-Fri) of a month. This is what I have so far. Any suggestions on improving?

For example, if I pass in October 30, 2020 it should return true, because Friday the 30th is the last weekday (Mon-Fri) that occurs in October.

For example, if I pass in October 31, 2020 it should return false, because the 31st is a Saturday (not Mon-Fri)

```
function isLastWeekday($dateObject){
    $last_day = new DateTime($dateObject->format( 'Y-m-t' ));
    $last_day_of_month = $last_day->format( 't' );
    switch( $last_day->format('N') ) {
            case 6:
                $last_day_of_month += -1;
            break;
            case 7:
                $last_day_of_month += -2;
            break;
    }

    if( $dateObject->format( 'Y-m-d' ) == $last_day->format( 'Y-m-' ).$last_day_of_month ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "last weekday of a month", and give a few examples (by editing your post)? If a month's last day is a tuesday, any tuesday should yield `true`?

Comment: @Jeto Edited title and post

Answer (score 1):

Using `strtotime()` and the [relative date formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php), this takes the date passed in (assuming a DateTime object) and formats it to the begining of next month and modifies it by `last weekday`, so for October 2020, this will give 2020-10-30 as the last weekday.  This is then compared against the timestamp from the original date passed in...

```
function isLastWeekday($dateObject){
    $end = clone $dateObject;
    $end->modify('first day of next month');
    return strtotime( $end->format( 'Y-m-d' ).' last weekday')
        == $dateObject->getTimeStamp();
}
```

Had a few issues with using the last day of month, so this is why it moves it on a month

Or just using DateTime objects...

```
function isLastWeekday($dateObject){
    $end = clone $dateObject;
    $end->modify('first day of next month')->modify('last weekday');
    return $end == $dateObject;
}
```